# How to regress on previous time step in R

Tags: r

How can I regress on the previous time step in R here? I want to regress deaths at time t based on deaths, guns, and shootings at time t-1.

```
City    Year  Month Deaths  Guns     Shootings
Miami   2010    1   69      73800       701        
Miami   2010    2   99      85050       738         
Miami   2010    3   122     92650       784
...
Miami   2013    5   204     99280       800
Miami   2013    6   234     110023      825        
Houston 2011    1   98      92100       789          
Houston 2011    2   146     103900      799         
Houston 2011    3   162     136100      772
```

Also in R, how do I use ggplot to show the month AND the year on the x-axis? I had a numeric date column in my dataset as well but I couldn't get it to plot by month and year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::lag` to lag the data and then fit the linear model. And, since a `dplyr` function is being used, I will do it in a pipe.

```r
x <- 'City    Year  Month Deaths  Guns     Shootings
Miami   2010    1   69      73800       701        
Miami   2010    2   99      85050       738         
Miami   2010    3   122     92650       784
Miami   2013    5   204     99280       800
Miami   2013    6   234     110023      825        
Houston 2011    1   98      92100       789          
Houston 2011    2   146     103900      799         
Houston 2011    3   162     136100      772'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

fit <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Guns = lag(Guns), Shootings = lag(Shootings)) %>%
  lm(Deaths ~ lag(Deaths) + Guns + Shootings, .)

summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Deaths ~ lag(Deaths) + Guns + Shootings, data = .)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#> -17.2273   0.8505  29.1597  53.4768 -63.1397 -38.9155  35.7956 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -9.668e+02  9.909e+02  -0.976    0.401
#> lag(Deaths)  2.567e-01  8.452e-01   0.304    0.781
#> Guns        -8.023e-03  8.976e-03  -0.894    0.437
#> Shootings    2.364e+00  2.152e+00   1.099    0.352
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 59.97 on 3 degrees of freedom
#>   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.3335, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.333 
#> F-statistic: 0.5004 on 3 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.708
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `year` and `month` to a date object using clock's `date_build` to ggplot the `Deaths` or `fitted` values etc. against the date.

And if you wanted separate lm models per `City` you could `nest` by `City` and iterate through the models using purrr's `map`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(clock)
library(broom)

# With some further made-up data
df <- tribble(
      ~City, ~Year, ~Month, ~Deaths,   ~Guns, ~Shootings,
    "Miami", 2010L,     1L,     69,  73800,       701,
    "Miami", 2010L,     2L,     99,  85050,       738,
    "Miami", 2010L,     3L,    122,  92650,       784,
    "Miami", 2010L,     4L,    204,  99280,       800,
    "Miami", 2010L,     5L,    234, 110023,       825,
    "Miami", 2010L,     6L,    244, 110500,       830,
  "Houston", 2011L,     1L,     98,  92100,       789,
  "Houston", 2011L,     2L,    146, 103900,       799,
  "Houston", 2011L,     3L,    162, 136100,       772,
  "Houston", 2011L,     4L,    182, 146100,       782,
  "Houston", 2011L,     5L,    192, 156100,       792
  )

df2 <- df |> 
  group_by(City) |> 
  mutate(date = date_build(Year, Month),
         lead_deaths = lead(Deaths)) |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  nest() |> 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(lead_deaths ~ Deaths + Guns + Shootings, data = .)),
         augmented = map(model, augment),
         fitted = map(augmented, ".fitted")) |> 
  unnest(c(data, fitted)) |> 
  ungroup() 

df2 |> 
  ggplot(aes(date, Deaths)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%b") +
  facet_wrap(~ City, scales = "free_x") +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>